# How can I (cleanly) bind a composed property to a view (MVM)?

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, properties, windows-phone

For my question, let's assume I have a viewmodel, model and view (MVVM). The viewmodel contains a couple of properties that change (and change the view via INotifyPropertyChanged event where they are binded).

Now I want to do something like a poly-property (i.e. take together a couple of string properties and put it into one property). How can I do this properly?

For example, I have three properties: Prop1, Prop2, Prop3 and want to make one property out of these: `PropNew = String.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", Prop1, Prop2, Prop3);`.

A possibility is to create a new property in the viewmodel (and update this if another property changes) which is then bound to the view. But I fear this is not clean... Are there other possibilities?

THank you!

Comment: I don't fully understand your terminology (e.g. a poly-property).  Maybe you could provide some sample code to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then you want to update the UI binding to a property on the view model that is *derived* from the current state of the class.

Notifying the UI in WPF is done by raising the `PropertyChanged` event on the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In the code snippet below I am using the `NotificationObject` from the PRISM library:

```
public class MyViewModel: NotificationObject
{
    private string _lastName;
    private string _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Greeting);
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Greeting);
        }
    }

    public string Greeting
    {
        get { return string.Format("Hello {0} {1}!", _firstName, _lastName); }
    }
}
```

Updating either of the `FirstName` or `LastName` properties will cause the UI to be notified that the `Greeting` property has changed, and that the data should be rebound.

Comment: Thank you. I did it without Prism (although it would be possible in Windows Phone)...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using MutiBinding and interface IMultiValueConverter?